# IE CSS DIsplay Issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

The products on the below page are getting displayed correctly in FF, Safari and IE8:

http://www.toomanydesigns.com/thefix/top10_watches/

However, IE6 is having issues.  Does anyone know what I need to do to get it to display correctly in IE6?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it.  I needed to add a larger line height to get the numbers to show and adjust the margins so the content fitted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have IE6 installed, but what this looks like is the [IE6 Multiple Class Bug](http://www.ryanbrill.com/archives/multiple-classes-in-ie/) for this (and maybe more) div:

```
<div class="listing-type-list catalog-listing top10full">
```

It's a bummer, but if you really need IE6 support, that page will show you some techniques to work around it.